# DRF Serialization Issue: Expected a dictionary, but got list

Tags: list, dictionary, celery, django-serializer

I'm working on a Django project using Django Rest Framework for API serialization. I have a Celery task that fetches data from an external API, processes it, and then saves it to my database using serializers.

Data in the external api looks like this

```
{
"shows": [
    "Boy Meets World",
    "Everybody Hates Chris",
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .(more tv show names)
    ]
```

}

Here's a simplified version of my task:

```
@shared_task
def fetch_and_save_all_shows():
    api_url = TV_SHOW_URL
    shows_url = f"{api_url}/quotes/shows"
    try:
        response = requests.get(shows_url)
        data = response.json()

        if isinstance(data, dict) and 'shows' in data:
            show_names = data['shows']

            # Ensure 'shows' contains a list
            if not isinstance(show_names, list):
                raise ValueError("Expected 'shows' to be a list.")

            # Convert the list of show names into a dictionary
            show_data = [{'shows': show} for show in show_names]

            # Pass the list of dictionaries to the serializer
            serializer = AllTvShowsSerializer(data=show_data, many=True)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid response data format")

    except Exception as ex:
        return {"error": f"An error occurred: {str(ex)}"}
```

The AllTvShowsSerializer expects a list of dictionaries with a key 'shows', and I'm attempting to convert a list of show names to this format.

However, I'm encountering two different errors:

When many is set to True, I get the error: "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
When many is set to False, I get the error: "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."
I'm not sure how to handle this situation correctly. How can I format the data to work with the serializer and avoid these errors?

Comment: When `many=True` expects dict and gets list because `show_data=[{'shows': 'Boy Meets World'}, {'shows': 'Everybody Hates Chris'}, ...]`
 
Can you give us the model and serializer?

Comment: HI @JimChr-R4GN4R I have fixed this issue. Could you help me with this question - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139187/tracking-the-completion-of-a-time-consuming-function-and-serving-csv-file-in-dja