# Tracking the completion of a time-consuming function and serving CSV file in Django APIView response

Tags: python, function, csv, django-rest-framework, tracking

I have an API built using Django's APIView class, which includes two endpoints: start_report_generation and get_csv. When I hit the start_report_generation endpoint, it triggers the execution of the generate_report function, which performs a time-consuming task, such as generating a report and creating a corresponding CSV file. On hitting the get_csv endpoint with a report ID, I want to check if the generate_report4 function has completed its execution and serve the generated CSV file as a response. If the function is still running, I want to return a response indicating that it is still running.

```
class TriggerReportView(APIView):
    def generate_report(self, request):
        report_id = generate_report4()
        return Response({'report_id': report_id}, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)

class GetReportView(APIView):
    def get_csv(self, request):
     report_id = req.query_params.get('report_id')
        # How can I track the completion of the `generate_report4` function and serve the CSV file?
        # How do I handle the case when the function is still running?

        return Response({'status': 'Running'})  # Placeholder response for now
or 
       return Response Response(csv_file, content_type="text/csv")
```

Comment: I think https://pypi.org/project/django-background-tasks/ is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You should start a background task on `start_report_generation` which will return 200 and run a task in background to generate a report. There will be an entry in some DB table indicating whether the task is done or running (depending on how you go about implementation) so you can just query that for the `get_csv` response.

You can integrate one of the existing task queues into your django app:

- [Huey](https://github.com/coleifer/huey)
- [Django-q2](https://github.com/django-q2/django-q2)

I would go against suggesting django-background-tasks and django-q since those projects are not being maintained.